# install pending software in sccm with powershell without admin rights

Tags: powershell, sccm

i'm tryin to install available software in microsoft sccm with powershell. problem is, that users, who are non admins, must run this script.
i have admin rights on the machines and its working fine. what do I have to change, that it is running. is it possible at all?
this is what i have. thats my script which is running with admin rights.

```
$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Function Invoke-AppInstallation {  
[CmdletBinding()]  
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)][string]$Computername,
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)][ValidateSet("Install","Uninstall")][string]$Method  
)

Get-CimInstance -ClassName CCM_Application -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ComputerName $Computername | %{   
    $arguments = @{
        EnforcePreference = [UINT32] 0  
        Id = "$($_.id)"  
        IsMachineTarget = $_.IsMachineTarget  
        IsRebootIfNeeded = $False  
        Priority = 'High'  
        Revision = $_.Revision
    }  

    Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ClassName CCM_Application -ComputerName $Computername -MethodName $Method -Arguments $arguments
}
}

Invoke-Appinstallation -computername $Name -method install
```

Comment: are there any ideas?

Comment: I don't really get the idea behind this. The whole point of "available" software is that it is not run automatically so why automate it? That being said it is absolutely possible to trigger the installation in SW Software with a non admin user. Are you having trouble triggering it or is the software itself set to install with user rights and thus the setup fails when those are missing? Is it working if you manually click Install in SW Center?